# Organic Groups Admin can't edit own group's user's profiles?

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

Using D7, does OG lack a very basic permission like `administrate users of own group`?

All I want is that a OG administrator can *edit* the **user profile** of the group members - but this doesn't seem to be possible.

I can give all *authenticated users* the permission `access user profiles`. Then the user profile page can be called and viewed by anyone else. I don't want that. And I cannot give the `administer users` permission to anyone.

I just want to have **administrators of a group** edit their user's profiles.

Did I overlook anything? Is there a group specific permission anywhere? All the OG permissions do not work here.

Only thing I found is [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26334) - but this seems hackish and not really a solution (and for D6).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a "basic permission" to me; that's not to say that it's impossible or not a completely valid request. Is this for Drupal 6 or 7? Because that response refers to 6.

Comment: Sorry, D7. I'll update that. Yes, I thought too that I have to write some code here. Just wanted to know if there is a simple answer. And I often **can't** believe that I am the first one who needs a solution for such a problem.